# Scraping from transfermarkt with R package rvest

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping, gsub, rvest

I'm learning to scrape data and I'm using transfermakt for it but today I've faced with two problems. I've used Selector Gadget. My code is this:

```
library(rvest)


url <- "https://www.transfermarkt.es/fc-granada/startseite/verein/16795"
webpage <- read_html(url)

players_html  <- html_nodes(webpage,"#yw1 .tooltipstered") 
players <- html_text(players_html) 
players

valores_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.rechts.hauptlink')
valores <- html_text(valores_html)
valores
valores <- gsub(" miles €","000", valores)
valores <- gsub(" mill. €","0000", valores)
valores
valores <- gsub(",","",valores)
valores <- gsub(" ","", valores)
valores
```

I've had the first problem selecting the players. This is the output.

```
> players_html  <- html_nodes(webpage,"#yw1 .tooltipstered")
> players <- html_text(players_html)
> players
character(0)
```

I think that the problem is in the CSS selector, but it's the one that shows me Selector Gadget when selecting players, so I don't know how to solve this.

The other problem occurs selecting their market values. Gsub doesn't remove some final whitespace that avoid putting characters as numbers. This is the output:

```
> valores_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.rechts.hauptlink')
> valores <- html_text(valores_html)
> valores
[1] "700 miles €  "  "300 miles €  "  "800 miles €  "  "500 miles €  "  
"300 miles €  " 
[6] "300 miles €  "  "1,00 mill. €  " "300 miles €  "  "1,20 mill. €  
" "500 miles €  " 
[11] "1,70 mill. €  " "1,50 mill. €  " "1,00 mill. €  " "800 miles €  
"  "800 miles €  " 
[16] "300 miles €  "  "2,00 mill. €  " "800 miles €  "  "700 miles €  
"  "400 miles €  " 
[21] "700 miles €  "  "1,00 mill. €  " "800 miles €  " 
> valores <- gsub(" miles €","000", valores)
> valores <- gsub(" mill. €","0000", valores)
> valores
[1] "700000  "   "300000  "   "800000  "   "500000  "   "300000  "   
"300000  "   "1,000000  "
[8] "300000  "   "1,200000  " "500000  "   "1,700000  " "1,500000  " 
"1,000000  " "800000  "  
[15] "800000  "   "300000  "   "2,000000  " "800000  "   "700000  "   
"400000  "   "700000  "  
[22] "1,000000  " "800000  "  
> valores <- gsub(",","",valores)
> valores <- gsub(" ","", valores)
> valores
[1] "700000  "  "300000  "  "800000  "  "500000  "  "300000  "  
"300000  "  "1000000  " "300000  " 
[9] "1200000  " "500000  "  "1700000  " "1500000  " "1000000  " 
"800000  "  "800000  "  "300000  " 
[17] "2000000  " "800000  "  "700000  "  "400000  "  "700000  "  
"1000000  " "800000  "
```

Basically, that last gsub used for removing final whitespace does nothing in this case. Could someone give me a hand with these two problems?

PS: I'm using transfermarkt in spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for `gsub`, we may use

```
valores <- html_text(valores_html)
valores <- gsub(" miles €", "000", valores)
valores <- gsub(" mill. €", "0000", valores)
valores <- gsub("\\D", "", valores)
valores
#  [1] "700000"  "300000"  "800000"  "500000"  "300000"  "300000"  "1000000" "300000"  "1200000"
# [10] "500000"  "1700000" "1500000" "1000000" "800000"  "800000"  "300000"  "2000000" "800000" 
# [19] "700000"  "400000"  "700000"  "1000000" "800000"
```

where `\\D` is anything other than a digit.

For player names we may write

```
players_html  <- html_nodes(webpage,"#yw1 span.hide-for-small a.spielprofil_tooltip")
players <- html_text(players_html) 
players
#  [1] "Rui Silva"             "Aarón Escandell"       "Bernardo Cruz"        
#  [4] "José Antonio Martínez" "Germán Sánchez"        "Pablo Vázquez"        
#  [7] "Álex Martínez"         "Adrián Castellano"     "Víctor Díaz"          
# [10] "Quini"                 "Nicolás Aguirre"       "Fede San Emeterio"    
# [13] "Ángel Montoro"         "Fran Rico"             "Alberto Martín"       
# [16] "José Antonio González" "Alejandro Pozo"        "Antonio Puertas"      
# [19] "Fede Vico"             "Daniel Ojeda"          "Álvaro Vadillo"       
# [22] "Adrián Ramos"          "Rodri"
```

In this way we also get only one set of (full) names. Using, e.g., `"#yw1 a.spielprofil_tooltip"` would also return their short versions.

Comment: Thank you. And why Selector Gadget doesn't show me the right CSS selector? I suppose that I'd have to look for in the source code of the web but it's not efficient. And how did you get that right selector?

Comment: @MiguelAnguita, I'm not at all an expert at this either. I just now tried Selector Gadget and also couldn't find how to get a good css from it. For the answer I used Safari Web Inspector to point me to the right place in the source code and then looked there myself. Sorry for having a better answer, but a good tool indeed seems to help!